# Using R, how can you extract colors and fonts used in a .png (or other format) image file?

Tags: r, image-processing, fonts, colors, png

Using R, how can I extract from an image file (.png or others are available) , and specifically the one below (you are right, it falls far from the finest embodiment of graphic visualization and best practices!) colors and fonts used?  I would like to find them out so I can reproduce exactly the colors used in the bars and the font used in their text labels.

For this question to be meet the standards of reproducibility, it may be necessary for me to provide the .png file, but I do not know how to do that for SO readers.  Tell me how, and I will do so.  Thanks

[image]

So, is there a way to identify the RGB or hex codes of the colors and the font family of the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an R problem, but you can get the color easily using this website:

[http://www.imagecolorpicker.com/en.](http://www.imagecolorpicker.com/en)

Just put the image url (https://i.stack.imgur.com/00W9N.png) in the box below, and then click to get the HTML/RGB colour code. You can then pass the color to a ggplot function.

For the font, I can't help. You might have luck over at graphic design:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote. @Lawyer is looking to identify the specific colours in an already rastered image. R is not the best hammer  to hit this nail, as you need to select individual pixels anyway, so why not use a color dropper. The font issue is also not really a stack overflow question.

Comment: is right.  The imagecolorpicker site worked wonderfully for me to extract the HTML (hex) codes I needed.  And, I will see if the other SO site, for graphic design, can provide a counterpart for finding fonts.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to understand is that PNG is a raster format, so you can only get pixel information (Red, Green, Blue channels) from image, not fonts, shapes, etc. Of course, there's a package for handling PNG format:

```
install.packages('png')
library('png')
pngImage=readPNG('test.png')
pngImage[293,1,]
# RGBA information of pixel at (1,293)
# [1] 0.09019608 0.13333333 0.20784314 1.00000000
```

If you want to extract text from the image, you can always use OCR software.

Comment: A big first step, but how do I find which pixels to extract RGBA from?  I have read in my .png file.  > str(pngImage)
 num [1:500, 1:700, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "info")=Dotted pair list of 3   Do I trial-and-error estimate the location of a bar, for example? and then pngImage[estimated coords]?
  ..$ dim       : int [1:2] 700 500
  ..$ bit.depth : int 8
  ..$ color.type: chr "palette"

Comment: You can look up coordinates of desired part of the image in any graphics editor - Paint on MS Windows, Pint on Ubuntu. As well as extract color. If it's a one-time task and you aren't planning any image processing, there's no need to do it in R in the first place.